# PHP announcements system errors

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a simple announcements system where you just type announcements in a box and it can be viewed by others. I get this error when I submit the form:

**Edit:**
Thanks, the php_announce.php now works, it does everything it's supposed to do, this is the new code :

```
<?php
// MySQL
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "testuser";
$password = "testpass";
$dbname = "testbase";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// Content
$content = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
$query="INSERT INTO announcements (content) VALUES ('$content')";
$conn->query($query)
?>
```

**Edit:** Thanks for the help I fixed the code like this:
after creating connection it does this:

```
$result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM announcements");
#print_r($result);
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

echo $row['content']. " <br><br> ". "<b>Posted by: You</b>";
echo "<hr width=100%>";
}
```

Comment: This is wide open for SQL Injection.  Look into MySQLi for PHP, or [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) when using user input in a database query.

Comment: It does not look like you have posted the current version of your code. I can't see how `$query = "SELECT * FROM announcements";` would cause a parse error.

Comment: I edited the code but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you need to provide a list of columns that correspond to the values you're trying to insert. e.g:

`$query="INSERT INTO announcements (content) VALUES ('$content')";`

Replace `content` with the name of the column in your table.

For the second one, the error message doesn't appear to correspond with the code you posted, but I'm guessing you forgot a semicolon on the preceding statement. Additionally, there's a missing `;` in your last `echo` statement, although I'm not sure if that's what's causing the specific message you posted. Please repost the latest code from `announce_out.php` and I'll try to help.

There are some other issues with this approach in general. You're mixing `mysqli` and the older `mysql`, which is going to cause you additional errors. Instead of calling `mysql_query()`, you should be using `$conn->query($query)` so that you're actually using the connection you are establishing with `new mysqli()`. Additionally, to prevent injection attacks, you should escape your `$content` variable in this way:

`$content = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['content']);`

This is a pretty basic way to escape strings and there are better methods like prepared statements that mysqli provides. I recommend checking out the page in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php

Comment: @Da1T Are you sure that is the current content of announce_out.php? The error you're getting does not match the code you've posted. Please double check.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate answer to your problem is:

You need to escape the content and let the function quote it for you.

```
$content= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content'], $conn);
$query="INSERT INTO announcements VALUES ($content)";
```

and you need a missing semicolon at the end of the echo statement.

```
echo $row['content']. " <br><br> ". "<b>Posted by: You</b>";
```

The long term answer is you should really look into a database abstraction layers which help you avoid incredibly dangerous errors you're likely to make (like incorrectly escaping content). See php manual for some basic ones: http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.abstract.php

But I also highly recommend using a higher level framework like Doctrine http://www.doctrine-project.org/.